# How to run a JAX-RS application on an embedded Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I want to run a JAX-RS 2.0 (Jersey) application on an embedded Tomcat (7). But I have not found an example or documentation about it.

How can I set up Tomcat 7 programatically and add a Servlet wrapping a JAX-RS application to it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you use maven to build a war file, all you need to do is upload the war using the tomcat manager app.

Comment: I don't want to build a war file, but to use Tomcat during development for unit testing and looking at the application with a browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start/stop Tomcat from Java environment, look at its startup scripts to see which classes are invoked. It's actually not that complex; I do this from my IntelliJ all the time. My IntelliJ startup config looks like this:

*Main Class*: `org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap`

*VM parameters*: `-ea -cp $CLASSPATH:/path/to/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base="/path/to/tomcat" -Dcatalina.home="/path/to/tomcat" -Djava.io.tmpdir="/path/to/tomcat/temp" -noverify -Xmx400M -XX:MaxPermSize=400M`

*Program parameters*: `start`

*Working directory*: `/path/to/tomcat`

If you want to stop Tomcat gracefully, the only different thing is *program parameters*, which is `stop`.